# ClassCastException vs instanceOf in Generic Collections

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception, instanceof

I have a class that implements `Collection<E>`.

When I check if my collection contains an item the interface's method give a parameter of object, when it's have to be an `<E>`

Do you think it's "normal" to write this code:

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o)
{
    E item;
    try
    {
        item=(E) o;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //check if contains "item"
}
```

I know that normally it's a terrible idea to check the type of an object with `try,catch`, but in a generic collection I can't check with `instanceOf` and I don't find a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) it says:

> Throws:  ClassCastException - if the type of the specified element is incompatible with this collection (optional)

So it is perfectly acceptable to code it like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        T item = (T) o;
        // ...
    }
```

and if the cast fails a `ClassCastException` is thrown.

You certainly should **not** hide that exception and quietly return `false` - that could leave many potential bugs in the user's code.

Comment: In the class `HashMap.EntrySet` in the source code I found this code -  `if (!(o instanceof Map.Entry))  return false;` So it's not so wrong to quietly return `false`.

Comment: @chmouelkalifa - You are correct - there are edge cases where returning `false` is acceptable but you should use `instanceof` (as they have done in `HashMap`) to detect that, not a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: of course. but in this case (of generic collection) I can't do it! (something about erasure of type, I don't really understand it)

Answer (score 2):

If your collection class has `E` as a generic type parameter with no bounds, your check is useless -- **the cast can't possibly fail**, because the cast is completely unchecked. `E`, if it is unbounded, is erased to `Object`, and your cast will be `item=(Object) o;`, which cannot fail. It could lead to other failures in other places down the line, but it can't fail here, and if it fails in other places later your try-catch doesn't catch it.

The fact you can't use `instanceof` should have told you something -- the reason `instanceof` cannot be used is because it is a runtime check, which needs the class at runtime to check, and you don't have the class at runtime. Trying to have a cast fail is also a runtime check, so it does not improve your situation at all. Relying on a cast to fail only works in the same situations that `instanceof` works, so it *NEVER* makes sense to "use a cast because `instanceof` doesn't work".

When you write generic code, it is important to consider what the code looks like after type erasure. When you erase generic code into non-generic code (by adding casts in appropriate places), the code should work the same. If it is not possible to write the code as non-generic, then it cannot be written as generic either.

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o)
{
    Object item;
    try
    {
        item= o;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e) // does this make sense?
    {
        return false;
    }
    //check if contains "item"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to throw `ClassCastException` in this method, so You must not check type. Read javadoc of Collection interface.

Answer (score 0):

Imho you should use equals / hashCode methods of parameter object to check if its present in your collection. Casting or instanceof is not required at all.